# Thinktecture Implicit Flow: Signout/Logout a user

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server, thinktecture-ident-model

I followed this example to get the implicit flow working.

http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2012/11/oauth2-in-thinktecture-identityserver-v2-implicit-grant-flow-with-javascript.html

My question is, how would I signout a user?  I'm hoping someone out there knows, because I haven't been able to find any examples.  Right now I can trigger the authorize window and process it all correctly and use the access token for my requests, but I don't know how to make it so I can switch users.

Answer (score 0):

To logout you have to create custom controller with logout method.

```
public void Logout()
{
   // You should be able to revoke thinktecture token like this. (haven't tested this out)
   var sam = FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule;  
   sam.SignOut();

   // Or you should be able to logoff like this when using a membership provider. (this way works for me)
   //_yourMembership.Logout();
   Thread.CurrentPrincipal = null;
   HttpContext.Current.User = null;
}
```

Here is a sample of token revocation:
https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot/blob/master/src/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot/Authentication/SamAuthenticationService.cs